# Google maps with multiple markers: create a new activity onMarkerClick

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I am trying to make a google map app that has a lot of markers and when the user clicks one of those markers, a new activity will open showing that marker's name and some additional info. I'm planning on putting buttons and stuff so I think infowindow won't cut it.

My code is a total mess since i'm a newbee and just put codes as long as they work so i'll just show the onMarkerClick part (where i am encountering the problem so it won't be too confusing

```
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker loc) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, stars.class);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    for (index3=0; index3 < array1.length; index3++) {    //array1 stores all of my markers' id
        if (loc.getTitle().equals(array5[index3])){       //array5 stores all of my markers' names
            bundle.putString("name", loc.getTitle());
            intent.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
        }

    return true;
    }
```

and my stars.java

```
public class stars extends MapsActivity {
String sname;
TextView tv;
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_stars);
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
    if(!bundle.isEmpty()){
        sname = bundle.getString("name");
        }
    tv.setText(sname);
    }

}
```

When i run this I get this error "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Bundle android.content.Intent.getExtras()' on a null object reference"
I tried making array5 public then use it in stars.java but it tells me that it's null. Also tried experimenting with bundle but i keep on getting the null error thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use this statement inside the onCreate method :

```
 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
```

And do check for nulls

```
if (bundle != null) {

    String sname = bundle.getString("name");                

}
```

Comment: it works nicely now! that was simple. spent hours trying to fix this. thanks a lot!